# Text/keyboard bug on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, keyboard

I was trying to post a question on the Android app, but the keyboard kept "jumping" in my way. Also, I couldn't hit the spacebar because the keyboard kept jumping off the screen.

Screenshot:

[image: keyboard stationary screenshot]

I am running Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy Discover, using the latest version of the Stack Exchange app (as of Dec. 16, 2014). I am using the stock Samsung keyboard.

Comment: Could you mention your device model and keyboard app (i.e. stock, or 3rd-party)? Also, since this is already quite old, could you try to repro this using the latest version (v1.0.83)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Updated question with requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed since I originally posted this problem.